# compare two fields in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am making this form, it is fee calculator, it has two fields, Fee Due and fee Paid then there is one saying balance and lastly the 4th field is text field saying status it auto updated using JavaScript according to balance as Paid, Unpaid or Instalments it is working fine but only issue is for some reason when certain specific values are entered status field goes blank it doesn't update according to the JavaScript it should say instalments, here is my JavaScript

```
    function ff_feecalc_new_init()
    {
        setInterval("calc()", 500)
    } 

    function calc(){

        ff_getElementByName('status').value='';
        ff_getElementByName('balance').value=Number(ff_getElementByName('amountdue').value)-Number(ff_getElementByName('amountpaid').value);

        if (ff_getElementByName('amountpaid').value==0 && ff_getElementByName('amountdue').value>0){

            ff_getElementByName('status').value="unpaid";
        }
        if(ff_getElementByName('amountpaid').value>0){
            if ((ff_getElementByName('balance').value <ff_getElementByName('amountdue').value){

                ff_getElementByName('status').value="installments";
            }
        }

        if (ff_getElementByName('amountpaid').value == ff_getElementByName('amountdue').value && ff_getElementByName('amountpaid').value>0){

            ff_getElementByName('status').value="paid";
        }
    }
```

Anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: There is a bracket missing

Comment: Where is there a bracket missing Chiel?

Comment: I'd suggest expanding your question with a jsfiddle for this. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I don't think any bracket is missing

Comment: Also why are we running calc every half second?

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use '===' instead of '==' in javascript comparisons. Try to use parseFloat() or parseInt() too.

Example:

```
if (parseInt(ff_getElementByName('amountpaid').value)===0 && parseFloat(ff_getElementByName('amountdue').value)>0){
...
}
```